# Is attachment to the word "Meditation" a problem?

Tags: meditation-practicalities, meditation-insight, meditation-recommendation, meditation-hindrances, meditation-effects

I like to Meditate, I like to read about Meditation, I like to think about Meditation; but the word ...

> "MEDITATION.. MEDITATION.."

... is always in my mind, I am attached to it.

How can I avoid this attachment?

I don't want to make Meditation as a PROBLEM. I just want to use it as a Solution. I think it will lead me to SUFFERING.

How I will meditate but remain unattached to it?

Answer (score 9):

You'll grow out of it eventually.  What you are experiencing right now is the honeymoon period.  Everyone goes through it.  It's no different than the start of a new relationship.  Everything is fresh, exciting, captivating.  The word discipline is meaningless.  How could you *not* want to sit!  There is absolutely nothing wrong with this.  Use this opportunity to learn as much as you can.  Sit as much as you'd like.  Work on developing your concentration.  Just like working out, the gains that come in the beginner phase have no equivalent at any other point in your practice.  Things are easy now.  Take advantage of them.

But everything fades in intensity.  Eventually, you are going to come to a point in your practice where maybe your sits aren't going so well.  Maybe progress isn't coming as fast as it was.  Perhaps you want to jump over and try a different tradition.  Who knows.  You might even find yourself getting bored from time to time.  All of this is also normal.  In fact, it's where the real practice begins.  From here on out, you will learn that while sitting reaps unimaginable rewards, they don't come without work.  Here, you get to stare face to face with the obstacles that are holding you back.  This is where you truly understand why one Zen koan calls "sitting long and getting tired" the heart of Buddhism.  These difficulties are all to be embraced.  They are what cause real transformation to occur.

Comment: very nice read!

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're answering, `I am attached to meditation`, or, `I am attached to the word "meditation"` ... I think the OP's question was the latter.

Comment: I had a tough time teasing out what he was asking.  I went with answering the final part of his question which was - "How will I meditate but remain unattached to it?"

Comment: Thank you @ChrisW.. you edit my question in well Format.. from next time..sorry from NOW I will write question in good format

Comment: @JyoSoudagar-Ajay You're welcome. I hope I understood you! I thought you wrote well: clearly and carefully. The syntax for formatting is called [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) and it's relatively simple (for software developers); it's summarized [here](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and also [here](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). The editor (input edit/text box) has an edit toolbar, but I never use it and instead I just type in the markdown directly.

Comment: Thank's once's again @ChrisW for helping me.. and thanks for the link..

Answer (score 3):

Here is the thing about attachment...

New Buddhists learn how bad attachment is and they immediately thing\k all attachments are bad. Any ironically no one care to ask "Are all the attachments bad?".

---

**Good attachments vs Bad attachments**

As you are afraid of bad attachments i assume you already know what they are so i will move on to good attachments.....

---

*Good attachments*

Not all the attachments are bad, For example the need to reach the end or the need to reach nirvana is an attachment. But without such an attachment you will not reach anywhere. So it is necessary for a being to have some incentive to work on something. And this is true to both good and bad things. So as you can see Lord Buddha never said that you should get rid of good ones along with the bad ones.

You must have this need to Meditate and you should feed it. This is called "Shraddha". Now you have realized the path and you are willingly going towards the goal.

---

**So what is good and what is bad?**

It is very simple...

If some attachment is driving you towards bad things you should try your best to get rid of that attachment.

It some attachment is driving towards the path or your personal practice you should keep that need and feed it, because it is your only true friend  to push you towards the path and away from other distractions.

---

Hope you well, and remember...

> The path is a one with comfort, But if you feel much discomfort it is because you are paying too much attention to insignificant details.If you keep practicing all the unnecessary attachments will fall without your influence and only good ones will last...

Comment: Thank a lot @Theravada... I will remember this.."The path is a one with comfort, But if you feel much discomfort it is because you are paying too much attention to insignificant details"

Comment: Glad i could help :-)  @JyoSoudagar-Ajay

Answer (score 2):

Just do it, Mr/Mrs Ajay. It's like if you are in love. Talking, thinking, hoping... and then remember the time when you have been in love, when it seems to lose interest or you tend to look for a side relation.

Comment: In German I think it is (or was) common [and even necessary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Herr#Usage_notes) to use a title like *Herr* or *Frau*, but so far as I know that's less true in common English. So I would usually address the OP as simply "Ajay" because that's the name they gave us. In English "Mr/Mrs Ajay" is quite formal (almost too formal): "Just do it, Ajay." would be less formal ... it would be familiar, and read as if you're trying to be friendly. Or it's common to omit the name entirely (e.g. "Just do it. It's like if you are in love.") to concentrate on the answer.

Comment: You seem to have two user accounts i.e. http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/7500/samana-johann and http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/7555/samana-johann ... is that deliberate or an accident? Why not use your (older) existing user account? It can be problematic if a person uses several different accounts. I urge you to use one single user account instead.

Comment: Maybe you can merge the accounts.

Comment: @Ajay This is the solution. Just do it but do it right. Doing something wrong would be problematic so be careful you are doing the right thing.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena No, I cannot merge the accounts. A user can contact SE to ask that their two accounts be merged, and SE can then do it. Moderators can delete an account, but not merge one with another.

Comment: To ChrisW's point, in modern American English to repeatedly use Mr. (e.g. Mr. Anderson) outside of a very formal situation would sound sarcastic.

Comment: Adressing in a polite way is also decaying in German, still better is the notion of politeness in Austria, but as soon people join Ikea and internet, such ways are forgotten. Atma had been killed for staying with that way... But/and it's a very good training to stay mindful, best, if Upasaka Chris uses generally 3. person. May valued Upasaka Chris it. In regard of the accound, Upasaka @ChrisW, that's just like anicca is. Atma would not urge to get this or hold on that. What ever is, is ok and it does not make so much stress, how to get ride of credits. May Mr/Mrs. Aya pardon this misuse here.

Comment: @SamanaJohann Should I understand that "the Samana" would prefer that I always address him using the "third person": like this, "the Samana"?

Comment: Unfortunately, in modern English and American, as explained in Andrei's comment above, emphasizing a title sounds so formal or unnatural that it can sound (or might make the hearer feel) distant, cold, reproving, alien, inhuman[e], caste-conscious, or even hostile; instead of friendly, intimate, or easy.  A German-speaker and some anglophones may intend it politely, but Andrei's saying (and he's not wrong) that it "would sound sarcastic" explains that it can be conventionally [mis]understood as being deliberately impolite, calling attention to the speaker, ...

Comment: ... and **[stand-offish](https://www.google.fr/search?q=define:stand-offish)**. I guessed that the Samana's mode of address is a polite carry-over from German: but, it may (I am afraid it will sometimes, which is why I am telling him this) make any his social interactions more **[prickly](https://www.google.fr/search?q=define:prickly)** if he always does that when he writes in English, to people who aren't accustomed to that form, on the internet. It was for that reason that suggested that the modes of address in my first comment, above, could be considered as a substitute.

Comment: Good is n.ly considered unnatural by people who are living in spheres of bad habits. Its not sarcastic to say wrong habits, which have been different, not long time ago, are wrong (not beneficial in measures of Dhamma & its aim). Atma does not struggle that much with that, maybe the audience do as it wishes. & U. Chris, if you like to try it, do it, no demand. Its (promised) a great challenge and on does not write faster as mindfulness would put one back. May you ask U. Dharmasena, if the ways of speaking would be able where he comes from or anybody would even talk with him, doing it "natural"

Comment: Chris is able to write in the third person and claims that he shouldn't find it "a great challenge", however that he is unlikely to do it unless it is expected or requested of him -- it is a habit, a convention, a mode of speech -- he fears that main challenge (and a potentially useless challenge at that) is the social friction it might cause, using language that's archaic and potentially irritating to its audience.

Comment: Actually one does not only speak in third person, but even give this person a certain position in regard of the other. There is where it become not only a habit, one does not easy keep even such a strange habit in an unmindful moment (try it), but also a permanent consideration of with whom one talks about and where one places ones position or give others in this way. Its a real good training, Upasaka Chris. Atma will not introduce further in this regard, since such ways would be as against the grain, as it could be. & yes, one is able to make people angry by being polite. Certain do not like.

Comment: Chris is grateful for the Samana Johann's advice, but remains concerned that over-using formal titles will be sometimes understood as impolite (the etymology of "polite" being "polished, smooth"). The Samana may consider this as part of Chris' advice about one's understanding of the English language.

Comment: Yes, that is reputation one fears to lose and not knowing what is the foremost and what is behind, people go on the level, lets orientate on the lowest or on the mass. But there is no need to fear the lose of reputations in regard of people which are worthy to do not lose ones reputation. It's a socializing thing, how to behavior that my food place does not become inaccessible. No need to worry, Upasaka Chris, Atma knows well what would be needed to be attractive if he would prefer that rather to give some capable a possibility. *It's like if you are in love. Talking, thinking, hoping...* OP?

Comment: If we both would be laypeople, it would be proper to address Upaska Chis with uncle, or my uncle, or Sir, or our moderator, or mr teacher, uhh... Atma would love it, if it would be proper, would Upasaka Chis? Maybe Atma should follow Upasaka Dharmasena suggestion to write more about [Apacāyana](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/13302/teachings-regarding-veneration-respect-as-one-of-the-traditional-10-meritorious?s=4|0.6680), since it is something one could practice everywhere.